# JavaScript not working as an external file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML, JavaScipt and everything related to programming, and I'm trying to create a simple page.

Now, I'm stuck with the following problem: I want to change the date of my `main.html` file, but the `main.js` is not working. I've already change the `<script>` position to inside the `<body>`, after the `</span>` and even after the `</body>`, without success. If the content of the `main.js` is within the HTML it works fine, but as a external file it doesn't.

Here is my main.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
        <title>Page 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>WRF<br>
        <span id="data">18/09/1987</span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

My main.js is just:

> document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "JUBA";

I've looked through the internet and through this forum, but all answers that I've found did not worked.

The files are on the same directory and the main.css works fine.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Document Object Model (DOM)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) is not "READY".

Try use `onload` event, inside main.js:

```
window.onload = function() {
     document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "JUBA";
};
```

If needs more "fast" than `onload`, use jquery with `$(document).ready`:

html:

```
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#data").html("JUBA");
});
```

---

### [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

Answer by @Guffa:

The `ready` event occurs after the HTML document has been loaded, while the `onload` event occurs later, when all content (e.g. images) also has been loaded.

The `onload` event is a standard event in the DOM, while the `ready` event is specific to jQuery. The purpose of the `ready` event is that it should occur as early as possible after the document has loaded, so that code that adds functionality to the elements in the page doesn't have to wait for all content to load.

Comment: Inside the main.js, right? Well, it didn't worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Juarez Yes, into main.js file :)

Comment: Nothing yet, @Guilherme... The problem is that the date will be automatically updated latter, thats why I want this on a separate file, otherwise it will be to many things on my html (well, to me at least hehehehe).

Comment: @Juarez Explain please, what does not work? The console emits an Error?

Comment: No, it just not changes the date to JUBA

Comment: @Juarez So you want to change exactly "what"? This is not in your question, is just that the code did not work. Please add details in your question. What exactly "<span id=data>" must receive? I wait Thanks!

Comment: Your answer was right, I was missing a symbol on the main.js, Thanks a lot, @Guilherme.

Comment: @Juarez Ok, I wish you much success in your projects :)

Answer (score 1):

At time you call main.js element `#data` was not created in DOM tree. You can fix this by putting the link to your Javascript file right before closing the body like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
 </body>
```

Comment: Didn't do it. Thanks anyway =]

Comment: It has to do it Juarez, you must be having other errors in script.

Answer (score 0):

The element is not yet accessible when you run the script. 
Either you can put the `script` at the end of the page or delay the execution.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the JavaScript in the `<body>` tag after the rest of the page. When the browser loads it, the `<span>` will already be there to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code the script will be called first then page will be loaded, therefore when the script is running there will not be any element having id data because yet page have to be loaded. There are many ways to achieve what you need.
1. Add a script tag before or after end of body like

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

2. Write .js file above before body i.e. in head tag and write the whole javascript code in onload method.

   window.onload=function(){
   document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "JUBA";
   };

```js
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "JUBA";
};
```

```html
 <p>WRF<br>
        <span id="data">18/09/1987</span></p>
```

Comment: You repeated my answer and the answer of @Katyoshah

Comment: Putting it on the html works, but as I've said to @Guilherme: The problem is that the date will be automatically updated latter, thats why I want this on a separate file, otherwise it will be to many things on my html (well, to me at least hehehehe).